# Modal Doesn't Display after removing from DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal that I that I use to display different partial views in the body.  I am trying to clear the body when the user closes the modal.  I am using the following code in the Document.ready of my Javascript:

```
        $('#PlanCertModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
        $('#PlanCertModal').remove();
```

This works fine in removing the modal from the DOM on hide, but after that I can no longer call "show" to display the modal.  It will not display:

```
                $('#PlanCertModal').modal('show');
```

I am using ajax to add the partial to the modal's body:

```
$.ajax({
        url: "@(Url.Action("AddPlanCertificateModal", "Management", new { area = "Operations" }))",
        data: { RequirementId: requirementId, PlanId:planId, EmployeeCompanyId: employeeCompanyId },
        type: "POST",
        success: function (data) {
            kendo.ui.progress(doc, false);
            $('#uploadForm').html(data);
            $('#PlanCertModal').modal('show');
        }
    });
```

Comment: if you remove an element from the DOM, of course you can't show it ... have you considered hide instead of remove?

Comment: Hiding it, just left the screen dim as if it were still open.  I need to remove the partial view from the body, and hide it.  I think I have actually figured it out.  I am testing it now.

Comment: so ... how did you try to hide it? `$('#PlanCertModal').modal('hide');` would be an educated guess

Comment: Yep, but also setting the html of the body to '', to clear the partial view.